# How to exclude email addresses from using remote SMTP?

Tags: sendmail, exim4

I have recently start using a remote smtp to send emails.

I have added this configuration lines inside my "exim.conf":

```
special:
driver = manualroute
domains = !+local_domains
transport = remote_smtp
route_list = * smtp.myisp.com
```

I want to add an exception for just few specific email addressed to bypass this remote smtp settings and use the default local server instead.

Anyone has any idea how to go about it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your ROUTERS and use following configuration.

```
special:
driver = manualroute
domains = !+local_domains
local_parts = f4fahmed
transport = remote_smtp
route_list = gmail.com gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com

special_route:
driver = manualroute
domains = !+local_domains
transport = remote_smtp
route_list = * smtp.myisp.com
```

To test them you can use following command.

**/usr/sbin/exim -C /etc/exim.conf -bt f4fahmed@gmail.com**

**Note:** make sure you will restart your exim to reload configuration.